# Image with rounded corners and shadow Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

How can I do something like this with Kivy?
[image: Example]

Comment: Vitor, edit your question and include the image not the link, a link can sometime be broken

Answer (score 6):

Use the button's [background_normal](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html?highlight=button#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_normal), [background_down](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html?highlight=button#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_down), and [border](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html?highlight=button#kivy.uix.button.Button.border) to achieve this. Lets name the two pictures that you provided as *normal.png* and *down.png*. Please refer to the example below for details.

## Snippets

```
Button:
    background_normal: 'normal.png'
    background_down: 'down.png'
    border: 30,30,30,30
```

## Example

### main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<RoundedButtons>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: '[color=3333ff][b]Rounded Button 1[/b][/color]'
        markup: True
        background_normal: 'normal.png'
        background_down: 'down.png'
        border: 30,30,30,30
    Button:
        text: '[color=ff3333][b]Rounded Button 2[/b][/color]'
        markup: True
        background_normal: 'normal.png'
        background_down: 'down.png'
        border: 30,30,30,30
""")


class RoundedButtons(BoxLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RoundedButtons()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Button 2 Down]