# how to add shadow to button in kivy?

Tags: kivy

I've seen this: [Image with rounded corners and shadow Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50133422/image-with-rounded-corners-and-shadow-kivy)
but how do you get the shadow background image for the shadow? how do you make a shadow for a button in kivy?

Comment: I suggest googling "How to Add Drop Shadow in GIMP".

Comment: I can't do gimp

Comment: how do you do the shadow

Comment: and what is gimp'

Comment: Oh, Thanks you so much