# why is kivy button shadow not appearing?

Tags: kivy

I've been trying this:[Image with rounded corners and shadow Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50133422/image-with-rounded-corners-and-shadow-kivy) and anyway I've made a drop shadow in GIMP or GNU Image Manipulation Program, The image is called 1.png

**1.png**
[image]
I'm trying to make the shadow appear
and I've tried the link above's code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<RoundedButtons>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: '[color=3333ff][b]Rounded Button 1[/b][/color]'
        markup: True
        background_normal: '1.png'
        background_down: '1.png'
        border: 30,30,30,30
    Button:
        text: '[color=ff3333][b]Rounded Button 2[/b][/color]'
        markup: True
        background_down: '1.png'
        background_normal: '1.png'
        border: 30,30,30,30
""")


class RoundedButtons(BoxLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RoundedButtons()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

and this the output

**output**
[image]

I'm not really getting what I wanted as my output, I've got confused because when I was viewing the image on my computer its showing a pattern in the background - **I knew** that the image had a deleted/invisible background -
here's how it looks like:
**viewed image**
[image]

I'm running it on a Chromebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your drop shadows are there, they are just hard to see with a dark background. Try changing your `kv` to:

```
<RoundedButtons>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Button:
        text: '[color=3333ff][b]Rounded Button 1[/b][/color]'
        markup: True
        background_normal: '1.png'
        background_down: '1.png'
        border: 30,30,30,30
    Button:
        text: '[color=ff3333][b]Rounded Button 2[/b][/color]'
        markup: True
        background_down: '1.png'
        background_normal: '1.png'
        border: 30,30,30,30
```

Adding the white background to the `RoundedButtons` makes the shadow more obvious.